# How to iterate through autocomplete suggestions in IPython shell

Tags: python, shell, console, ipython

I'm wondering how to iterate through suggestions that you can see after tapping TAB (or you must type one of them manually?)
Ex:

[screenshot with suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyP98.png)

How to choose one of the variants?

Comment: Keep tabbing and then hit enter... or did you mean doing it programmatically?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If i just tabbing more it just shows variants once again. Like this https://imgur.com/tsXsdpr

Comment: _TAB_ and then when you found what you desired press _ENTER_. As @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ said.

Comment: what version of `ipython` are you using? That looks old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of IPython you are using uses readline, that is to say you are either using IPython 4 or earlier, or have setup IPython 5+ to use readline. Thus you cannot really iterate over completions, you can type to give more hints to IPython. Update to IPython 5+ to get better completions.